# Перевод числа с плавающей точкой в двоичную систему счисления

Tags: python, математика

Как на языке программирования Python переменную float перевести в двоичную систему счисления без математики и библиотек, которые нужно скачивать?

Я делаю библиотеку, которая должна точно выводить точный ответ на математические примеры, но я не смог придумать способ перевода дробной части, с помощью которой можно будет переводить все числа, не используя математику и библиотек, которые нужно скачивать.

Comment: как точный ответ связан с двоичным представлением чисел ?

Comment: n1tr0xs, я для библиотеки хотел использовать двоичные числа потому, что их можно считать с помощью условий, мне в библиотеке нельзя использовать математику из-за их неправильных ответов. (```print(0.3-0.2)```)

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдёт модуль fractions

Comment: Может тогда представите задачу в общем, а не идею относительно условной математики на двочиных числах? Может вам нужно правильно сравнивать `0.3-0.2==0.1`?

Comment: Acinit, мне нужно сделать библиотеку, которая будет считать правильно, мне в основном проекте нельзя использовать неточные ответы. (Пример неточного ответа: ```print(0.3 - 0.2)```) Библиотека готова, но осталось только сделать перевод чисел в двоичную систему.

Comment: Ну по русски говоря, вам нужно считать "точно", так???? Зачем для этого издеваться над двочиным представлением чисел с плавающей точкой?

Comment: «не используя математику» — это очень смешно, да

Comment: модуль `decimal` не подойдет? вот [справка](https://sl.bing.net/dxkozX1Ihgq) от GPT.  ЭТо точно будет десятичная арифметика с точно наперед заданной точностью. Точнее чем любое двоичное представление числа флоат ).  Может  -  это и есть та библиотека, которую вы делаете? "Всё уже написано до нас"  (с)

Comment: А что вы будете делать, если у вас в результате деления получится бесконечная десятичная дробь?

Comment: Работайте с рациональными числами. https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html. Любой другой способ будет делить не точно.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте экспоненциальную форму представления чисел с основанием 10, мантиссу и порядок храните целыми числами, величина которых в Питоне не ограничена.

Ваш пример будет выглядеть так:

```
(3, -1) - (2, -1) = (1, -1) # (мантисса, порядок)
```

Comment: Ну и правильно. Вы написали `print(0.3-0.2)` - это же в десятичной системе? Поэтому, чтобы из конечных десятичных дробей не получались бесконечные двоичные (со всеми вытекающими эффектами), и нужно хранить число в экспоненциальной форме с основание 10, а не 2, как это в float & double.

Comment: Не путайте машинное представление числа и основание экспоненциальной формы представления. Машинное представление у нас двоичное, что бы там не было наверху, даже символы. А вот при преобразовании из `c10*10^b10` в `c2*2^b2` как раз и происходят такие беды, когда `0.3-0.2!=0.1`. Поэтому оставайтесь в `c10*10^b10`, где c10 и b10 - это целые числа (машинно они будут в двоичном виде, как и всё остальное). Почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008.

Comment: Как успехи в решении?